# Overwrite record after Search -MVVM WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a View ConfigRole which contains DataGrid with two Columns: View and IsEnabled(CheckBox), and a Search area.

and the Button Save it works correctly, I make all views which I want IsEnabled and I save it :
for exemple:

[image]

And when I use the search box, I have the correct result for all the views I search on it,for exemple I write 'Customer' in search box ,I have all the views with the key 'Customer':

[image]

My problem is when I make Save Button after Search ,all the CheckBox (IsEnabled in the first View will be FALSE !! just the Views I make it Enabled in the Search view are Save !

[image]

XAML ConfigRole:`

```
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox" Text="{Binding ViewName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
     NotifyOnValidationError=True ,TargetNullValue=''}" />

     <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid"  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedView}" ItemsSource="{Binding ViewList}"   
               CanUserAddRows="False" AlternationCount="2" AlternatingRowBackground="Blue" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >

                <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="View" Binding="{Binding ViewCode}"  IsReadOnly="True" />

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Is Enabled" Width="Auto">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsEnabled, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
           </DataGridTemplateColumn>       
        </DataGrid.Columns>

       </DataGrid>
    <Button Command="{Binding  SaveRole}"  Visibility="{Binding Path=ShowSaveButton, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=ConfigureRole}"/>

</Grid>
    `
```

ConfigRoleViewModel:
         `private ObservableCollection<ViewRoleMapClass> _viewList;
         private MiniTasServicesClient WCFclient = new MiniTasServicesClient();

         public int test;`
          public static event refreshList _refreshList = delegate { };

```
 public ConfigRoleModel(int RoleId,ObservableCollection<UserRoleClass> roleList)
    {
        test = RoleId;
        _viewList = new ObservableCollection<ViewRoleMapClass>(WCFclient.getViewRoleMapsByRole(RoleId));       
         saveRole = new RelayCommand<Window>(configRole);
   ConfigRoleModel._refreshList += this.refreshRoleList;       
    }   
       private void refreshRoleList()
         {             
             _viewList = new ObservableCollection<ViewRoleMapClass>(WCFclient.getViewRoleMapsByRole(test));
             OnPropertyChanged("ViewList");
         }  

     private RelayCommand<Window> saveRole;
     public RelayCommand<Window> SaveRole
    {
        get { return saveRole; }
    }


    //all list of Views 
    public ObservableCollection<ViewRoleMapClass> ViewList
         {
             get { return _viewList; }
             set
             {
                 _viewList = value;
                 OnPropertyChanged("ViewList");
             }
         }  

         //the Function of the Button Save
          private void configRole(Window window)
    {     
         List<ViewRoleMapClass> listViewRoleMap = new List<ViewRoleMapClass>();
        foreach (ViewRoleMapClass view in ViewList)
        {
            if (view.IsEnabled) listViewRoleMap.Add(view);
        }    
         int resultUpdate = WCFclient.updateViewRoleMap(listViewRoleMap, test);
         if (resultUpdate == 0)
            {
                string sCaption = "Save notification";
                string sInformation = "Save operation is performed successfully";
                MessageBoxButton btnMessageBox = MessageBoxButton.OK;
                MessageBoxImage icnMessageBox = MessageBoxImage.Information;

                MessageBoxResult rsltMessageBox = MessageBox.Show(sInformation, sCaption, btnMessageBox, icnMessageBox);                   
            }               
            _refreshList();
    }

    //Search        
         private string _viewName;
         public string ViewName
         {
             get { return _viewName; }
             set
             {
                 _viewName = value;
                 OnPropertyChanged("ViewName");
                _viewList = searchByCriteria(ViewName);
                 OnPropertyChanged("ViewList");
             }
         }           
          private ObservableCollection<ViewRoleMapClass> searchByCriteria(string _viewName)
         {
             List<ViewRoleMapClass> resultSearch=new List<ViewRoleMapClass>();                 
             _viewList = new ObservableCollection<ViewRoleMapClass>(WCFclient.getViewRoleMapsByRole(test));                 

             if (_viewName != null)
             {
                 resultSearch = _viewList.Where(c => c.ViewCode.ToLower().Contains(_viewName.ToLower())).ToList();                       
             }                   
             return new ObservableCollection<ViewRoleMapClass>(resultSearch);                            
         }
```

My class:

```
  public class ViewRoleMapClass : ViewModelBase
   {
    private int _id;
    private bool _isEnabled;
    private int _userRoleId;
    private int _viewListSetId;
    private string _viewCode;

    public int id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set
        {
            _id = value;
            ValidateAsync();
        }
    }

    public bool IsEnabled
    {
        get { return _isEnabled; }
        set { _isEnabled = value; }
    } ...

 }  
   `
```

And the IsEnabled located in the method search and in the function configrole(for the button Save):`if (view.IsEnabled) listViewRoleMap.Add(view);`
if it is TRUE, Save in the List listViewRoleMap

the Web Service updateViewRoleMap:

```
         public int updateViewRoleMap(List<ViewRoleMapClass> listViewRoleMap, int roleId)
         {
          try
         {
            UserRole userRole = modelMiniTms.UserRoles.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == roleId);
            if (userRole == null)
                //user role is null
                return 2;
            List<ViewRoleMap> myListViewRoleMap = modelMiniTms.ViewRoleMaps.Where(a => a.UserRoleId == roleId).ToList();
            foreach (var viewRoleMap in myListViewRoleMap)
            {
                int index = listViewRoleMap.FindIndex(a => a.id == viewRoleMap.Id);
                viewRoleMap.IsEnabled = index >= 0;
                modelMiniTms.ViewRoleMaps.AddOrUpdate(viewRoleMap);
            }
            modelMiniTms.SaveChanges();

         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
            string input = String.Empty;
            log.WriteLogFile(userName, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, input, ex.Message);
            return 1;
         }
          log.logDataBase(userName, LogFile.OperationType.Update.ToString(), "ViewRoleMapClass", roleId.ToString());
         return 0;
        }
```

How can I fix it?

Thanks,

Comment: Check if you are overwriting "IsEnabled" of previously saved views.

Comment: So where are you setting the IsEnabled property of the ViewRoleMapClass in your code?

Comment: @mm8 I have edit my post with the class and little description of IsEnabled

Comment: It is still unclear where you *set* the property.

Comment: I add the web service where the save of IsEnabled, 
It is OK now?
the Web service just i make call for it..

Comment: How is the _refreshList method defined?

Comment: @mm8 I had edit the code: I add the function _refreshList()

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing your problem comes from the `searchByCriteria` method.

I see you are reinitializing the `_viewList` collection in the second line of the aforementioned method. It's possible that by doing that you are losing the things you saved from the view. I understand you need the data, but I think you would need a property of `ObservableCollection<ViewRoleMapClass>` just for the binding, something along the lines of this:

```
private ObservableCollection<ViewRoleMapClass> _fullData; // replaces _viewList
public ObservableCollection<ViewRoleMapClass> ViewList { get; private set; }

private void searchByCriteria(string _viewName)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_viewName))
    {
        resultSearch = _fullData.Where(c => c.ViewCode.ToLower().Contains(_viewName.ToLower())).ToList();
        ViewList = new ObservableCollection<ViewRoleMapClass>(resultSearch);
    }
    else
        ViewList = _fullData;                                      
}
```

In this way only the object that is being used to populate the grid is modified, not the actual source of the data.

And your constructor becomes:

```
public ConfigRoleModel(int RoleId) //You don't need that collection in the parameter list since it doesn't look like you are using it
{
    test = RoleId;
    _fullData = new ObservableCollection<ViewRoleMapClass>(WCFclient.getViewRoleMapsByRole(RoleId));       
    saveRole = new RelayCommand<Window>(configRole);
    ViewList = _fullData;
}
```

I hope I made myself clear.

Have a nice day

Comment: Thanks for your help,
but it still yet the same problem ..when I save the Views comes in the search ,all the old enabled views becmos FALSE

Comment: @devtunis Check the `_refreshList()` method which is being called at the end of the `configRole` method. It seems that method is being called whenever you click Save, regardless of the update result.

Comment: I have verified it, and I didn't find any problem in _refreshList()

Comment: I made a small example on my side without the service call and my code as I posted it above works as expected. After I looked over your stuff which you later added, it seems the problem lies within the `_refreshList()` method.

Comment: I had edit the code: I add the function _refreshList()